# Issue in Twitter Search Rest API Version 1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am trying to implement the Twitter Search in my application.
There wasn't any issue with the Version 1 ([Rest API](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=keyword)).
But now the Version 1 is deprecated, I have to migrate to Version 1.1

Here the new [url](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=freebandnames) is returning to Bad Authentication as response.
Do I need an oauth for this?
If no, how I can I use the updated version's API?

Answer (score 2):

With version 1.1 you'll need to authenticate for all types of requests.

> **Authentication required on all endpoints**
>
> In version 1.1, we're requiring applications to authenticate all of
>   their requests with OAuth 1.0a or Application-only authentication.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview#Authentication_required_on_all_endpoints

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to develop an app for my localhost, just for the sake of learning.(But while registering the app, they asked my for my domain name)
please let me know, the steps involved in incorporating the search API of twitter